# Why does std::condition_variable take a unique_lock instead of a lock_guard?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

[`std::condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) in use as the following:

```
std::condition_variable cv;
...
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
cv.wait(lk, []{return processed;});
```

Seems to me to have an interesting problem. `unique_lock` could be deferred, it could have been swapped away. It could have numerous other reasons by code design and not necessarily bad mistakes that it is not actually locked. eg.

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m, std::try_to_lock_t); // or  std::defer_lock_t
// Try to lock fails.
cv.wait(lk, []{return processed;});
```

Why not enforce a locked situation by making `std::conditional_variable` work with `lock_guard` instead? Then you would be very hard pressed to get into this situation. In fact the only way would be to do this:

```
// m is not already locked
std::lock_gaurd<std::mutex> lk(m, std::adopt_lock);
cv.wait(lk, []{return processed;});
```

Rather than the multitude of ways available in `unique_lock`. **Is there a technical reason to use `unique_lock` over `lock_guard` for a `condition_variable`**?

Comment: The question title is exactly the question asked here. The accepted answer covers all bases (even more than the current answers here). The OP does indeed make it about `mutex` vs `unique_lock`, but the highest voted answer covers so much more, including a dedicated paragraph on why not `lock_guard`.

Comment: @rubenvb You are absolutely right. I must have missed that paragraph when i read the answer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem. Duplicates primarily serve to direct users and visitors to good comprehensive answers. It's not a slap on the wrist or anything. Just a [303 See other](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The condition variable needs to be able to lock and unlock the mutex, `lock_guard` doesn't allow this. `lock_guard` also doesn't allow access to the mutex itself which most condition variable implementations probably require.

Answer (score 1):

`lock_guard` and `unique_lock` are pretty similar. However a `lock_guard` locks on construction and unlocks on destruction. Using `condition_variable` the mutex needs to be possible locked and unlocked multiple times.

You can basically use `unique_lock`s everywhere, however they impose more overhead than a simple `lock_guard`.

> std::condition_variable works only with std::unique_lock;
>   this restriction allows for maximal efficiency on some platforms.
>   std::condition_variable_any provides a condition variable that works
>   with any BasicLockable object, such as std::shared_lock.

taken from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)